# Execute function on each element (with the same id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="dadosalvaje" class="draconistone"><dl class="codebox"><dd><strong>Número aleatorio (1,10) : </strong>1</dd></dl></div>

<div id="dadosalvaje" class="draconistone"><dl class="codebox"><dd><strong>Número aleatorio (1,10) : </strong>3</dd></dl></div>
```

And i want to execute this JavaScript code on each one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Arreglos
    var zonas = ['draconistone','cessabit', 'valoran'];
    var draconistone = ['bulbasaur', 'pikachu', 'squirtle'];

    //Variables
    var contenedor = $('#dadosalvaje');
    var texto = contenedor.text().split(' ');
    var resultado = texto.pop();
    var zonaID = $('#dadosalvaje').attr('class');

    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonaID == zonas[i]) {
            if (zonaID == 'draconistone') {
                var pokemonSprite = draconistone[resultado - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonas[i] == zonaID) {
            contenedor.append('<img src="https://www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados/' + pokemonSprite + '.gif"><div class="salvajeNombre">' + pokemonSprite + '</div>');
            contenedor.attr('id', 'salvajelisto');
        }
    }
});
```

It just affects the first element and I can't find the way to modify both of them.

Is there any way to modify every single element with the same ID ?

Comment: Id's should be unique in the document. Your current markup is invalid.

Comment: `id` **must** be unique. This is not optional. You cannot have more than one element with any given id.

Comment: Use classes and iterate over each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to make unique id
2. You do not need the "draconistone" class

Inside the $(document).ready(function() { and }); tags make the code a function with an id parameter like this:

```
function name(id) {
    //Arreglos
    var zonas = ['draconistone','cessabit', 'valoran'];
    var draconistone = ['bulbasaur', 'pikachu', 'squirtle'];
    //Variables
    var contenedor = $('#' + id);
    var texto = contenedor.text().split(' ');
    var resultado = texto.pop();
    var zonaID = $('#' + id).attr('class');

    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonaID == zonas[i]) {
            if (zonaID == 'draconistone') {
                var pokemonSprite = draconistone[resultado - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonas[i] == zonaID) {
            contenedor.append('<img src="https://www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados/' + pokemonSprite + '.gif"><div class="salvajeNombre">' + pokemonSprite + '</div>');
            contenedor.attr('id', 'salvajelisto');
        }
    }
}
```

Then execute the functions with the two different ids as parameters.

Comment: It has to be `var zonaID = $('#'+id).attr('class');` then.

Comment: You edited the wrong line. Well, not the wrong one, but at least not the one I was referring to.

Comment: there, i changed it

Comment: This is the one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use $.each()
Like this

```
$('.draconistone').each(function() {
  var zonaID = $(this).attr('class');
  ..
});
```

Comment: `$('#dadosalvaje')` will find only the first element with that `id` - for good reason. Another element with the same id is not allowed to exist. So a) this doesn't work and b) rightfully so. You shouldn't suggest a solution that allows OP to stay on duplicate ids.

Comment: Sorry! $('.draconistone')

Answer (score 0):

There is one for the same class

```js
$( document).ready(function() {
  $( ".draconistone" ).each(function( i ) {
     var zonas = ['draconistone','cessabit', 'valoran'];
    var draconistone = ['bulbasaur', 'pikachu', 'squirtle'];

    //Variables
    var texto = this.innerText.split(' ');
    var resultado = texto.pop();
    var zonaID = this.className;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonaID == zonas[i]) {
            if (zonaID == 'draconistone') {
                var pokemonSprite = draconistone[resultado - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < zonas.length; i++) {
        if (zonas[i] == zonaID) {
            this.innerHTML += '<img src="https://www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados/' + pokemonSprite + '.gif"><div class="salvajeNombre">' + pokemonSprite + '</div>';
            this.id = 'salvajelisto';
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dadosalvaje1" class="draconistone"><dl class="codebox"><dd><strong>Número aleatorio (1,10) : </strong>1</dd></dl></div>

<div id="dadosalvaje2" class="draconistone"><dl class="codebox"><dd><strong>Número aleatorio (1,10) : </strong>3</dd></dl></div>
```

Comment: **id must be unique. This is not optional. You cannot have more than one element with any given id.**

Comment: I did not say you can. I said class

Comment: I dont care its his code I just made it it can loop through his div and it works. Im happy if he is happy. and i suggest you go and be happy too.

Comment: If you don't care about the correctness and quality of your answers, StackOverflow is going to be a rough place for you. And rightfully so.

Comment: Its not about me. nor you. he just wanted us to fix his problem and we did.

Comment: By the way you can suggest edit for an answer instead down vote and ragging in comment

Comment: You don't understand that OP getting the answer he was looking for is only part of the purpose of StackOverflow. And that is even like the smaller part of it.